# Creating a variable to store objects of classes that inherit from the same class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am trying to create an inventory that can store item of different types.

Is there anyway I can solve this problem IF I only use one variable for the inventory for each tile AND that I don't try to put every type of item into one class?

Here is some code I have started doing:

Tile class:

```
public class Tile
{
    public Item inventory;
}
```

Item class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Item
{
    public itemType type;
}

public enum itemType
{
    crop,
    tool,
    cooker,
    dish
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

EDIT: This is solved by using polymorphysm, casting the derived classes to the base class.

Comment: Would you have any code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes, it is possible." If you want a more specific answer please try to provide a specific question. A code example might help.

Comment: ok i have provided some code in the description of the question

Comment: Can you share the relevant code.? Seeing code will make the problem more visible then reading the problem description.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I edited code into the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface that all items implement. That way you can have many classes implement the interface and set their instances to the `type` variable in your Tile class

IItem interface

```
public interface IItem
{
    public itemType type {get; set;}
}
```

Item class implements the interface

```
public class Item : IItem
{
    public itemType type {get; set;}
}
```

Tile class

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile
{

    public List<itemType> allowedItems;

    public IItem inventory;

    public virtual void interact (IItem item, PlayerInteraction player)
    {
        foreach (itemType allowedItem in allowedItems)
        {
            if (allowedItem != item.type)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (inventory == null && item != null)
            {
                player.setItem(inventory)
                inventory = item;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the `{get; set;};` in the item interface do?

Comment: It is a property. As far as I know interfaces cannot have plain variables they need to be properties. You can read more about properties here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: so the get and set methods are members that are required to be added in a interface?

Comment: i will try this out. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: c# has build in getters and setters. In other OOP languages you had to create public get and set methods to make a private variable accessible to other classes but in c# you use the get and set keyword. You can see examples and an in-depth explanation in the link I sent you above.

Comment: I have tried to implement the get and set methods: `public interface IItem
{
public itemType type
{
get
{
return type;
}
set
{
type = value;
}
}
}` yet it generates an error: `target runtime doesn't support default interface implementation`

Comment: @IllegalRazer Are you building Unity apps?

Comment: default interface implementation is C# 8 feature, for now you'll need to use the alpha https://unity3d.com/alpha/2020.2a version

Comment: @IllegalRazer your code is not correct (it's recursion on itself)

Comment: @appleapple why is it recursion? Sorry this is my first time dealing with interfaces in classes

Comment: @IllegalRazer well, the `return type;` literally return itself, it's like `itemType GetType(){return GetType();}`

Comment: oh i meant to return the value of the variable `itemType type`, not the method/function. What should I do If i need the get method to return the value of `type`?

Comment: @IllegalRazer you cannot have member variable in c# `interface`.

Comment: @IllegalRazer Note that the same `public itemType type {get; set;}` in `class` has different meaning, 1. it implement the interface, 2. it's [auto implement property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) there.

Comment: @IllegalRazer BTW, for or your example I don't think you actually need to use `interface`, you can simply remove `IItem` and [keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: so will the following code work?:`public class crop{ ... public Crop(){ type = itemType.Crop } ...}`

Comment: @appleapple By keeping it simple, do u advise me to fit all the attributes of crops, pots etc all into the `Item` class?

Comment: @IllegalRazer 1. yes, it'd work. (if `class Crop` inherit from `class Item`)

Comment: @appleapple but if `class Crop` inherits from `class Item`, does that mean that I have to use separate variables for crop, tool, dish etc in `class Tile`?

Comment: @IllegalRazer 2. well no, but if it make you easy to understand what you're doing, then you can always refactor later. (and you say you don't want to use class in question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218796/discussion-between-illegalrazer-and-apple-apple).

Comment: @IllegalRazer no, you store `Item` (the base class)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the base class or interface in `Tile`, and you can either add common method to the base type/interface or just [pattern match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) it.

The following code is based on [my discussion with OP](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218796/discussion-between-illegalrazer-and-apple-apple)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tile myTile = new Tile();
        Crop myCrop = new Crop();
        myTile.inventory = myCrop;
        myTile.do_something_pattern_matching();
        myTile.do_something_virtual_call();
    }
}

public class Tile
{
    public IItem inventory;
    public void do_something_pattern_matching()
    {
        //you can direct check the type, no need for `itemType` field
        if (inventory is Crop crop)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"I have a crop with age {crop.age}!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nothing special");
        }
    }
    
    public void do_something_virtual_call(){
      if(inventory!=null)
          Console.WriteLine($"The inventory is {inventory.type}!");
    }
}

public enum itemType{crop,tool,cooker,dish}

public interface IItem // prepend *I* just by convention
{
    // you don't really need this, but I leave it as example
    itemType type{get;}
}

public class Crop : IItem
{
    // same as itemType type{get{return itemType.crop;}}
    public itemType type => itemType.crop;
    public int age;
    public Crop()
    {
        age = 11;
    }
}
```